# Can I safely handle this caterpillar?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I just found this caterpillar in my garden. I’m about to mow the grass for the first time. Can I safely handle it? What type of caterpillar is it?

For reference, I’m in Leeds, UK. Here are some pictures:

[image]
[image]

It’s about 5cm long and 1cm wide. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of Googling I think I found it. It’s a pale tussock moth caterpillar. https://butterfly-conservation.org/moths/pale-tussock

It says it irritates the skin and can cause a nasty rash so I’m staying away for now.

I might risk moving it with a trowel and small tub though.